# How do I poblate a recyclerview that takes data from two tables?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-room

I'm working on a recyclerview that has two textViews inside.

One goes for the hour placed on one table
And the other one goes for the medicine name that's connected as a foreign key via id.

Thing is, how can I actually call those? I can't get two adapters in one RecyclerView, so how can I deal with this?

This is the item that I use for poblating the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/manzana_semi"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewH"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/verde_junta" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/medTextView"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/verde_junta" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an object that holds both the hour and the medicine like

```
class DataHolder{
 String hour;
 String Medicine;
}
```

in your recyclerview adapter let it take a list  of  this object to  populate its views.

in your activity/fragment get  data from your 2 different data sources and create objects of  this type then populate your recyclerview

Comment: Thanks! I tried this at like 4 am GMT and managed to get it working on the first try!